# ReferenceRepository strips related entities when calling getReference()

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am writing a Symfony 2 unit test that relies heavily on data fixtures.  As a shortcut, I wired up a method that will give me access to the fixture loader's `ReferenceRepository` so that I can access shared entities in my tests.

However, when I pull an object out of the `ReferenceRepository`, it has no relations, even though I persist them in the data fixture.

The weird part is, there is some code in `ReferenceRepository` that appears to be stripping those relations out, and I don't understand why it is doing this (let alone how to prevent it).

As an example, here is what a data fixture looks like:

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $project = new Project();
    // ... populate fields ...

    /* Add one detail field to the Project. */
    $detail = new ProjectDetail();
    // ... populate fields ...
    $project->addDetail($detail);

    $manager->persist($project);
    $manager->flush();

    $this->addReference('project-onedetail', $project);
}
```

In my test case, I am doing something (more or less) like this:

```
$project =
    $this->fixtureLoader->getReferenceRepository()
        ->getReference('project-onedetail');
```

When I call the method in the test case to grab this `Project` object, I notice some weird behavior:

From `Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\ReferenceRepository` (comments added):

```
public function getReference($name)
{
    $reference = $this->references[$name];

    // At this point, $reference contains the Project object with related ProjectDetail.
    //  It would be awesome if the method would just return $reference...

    $meta = $this->manager->getClassMetadata(get_class($reference));
    $uow = $this->manager->getUnitOfWork();

    if (!$uow->isInIdentityMap($reference) && isset($this->identities[$name])) {
        // ... but instead it goes into this conditional....

        $reference = $this->manager->getReference(
            $meta->name,
            $this->identities[$name]
        );

        // ... and now $reference->getDetails() is empty!  What just happened??

        $this->references[$name] = $reference; // already in identity map
    }

    return $reference;
}
```

What's going on in `ReferenceRepository->getReference()`?  Why are the related objects getting removed from `$reference`, and how do I prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

## What's Going On

After the fixture loader runs, it clears out the UnitOfWork's identity map.

See `\Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\AbstractExecutor`:

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager, FixtureInterface $fixture)
{
    ...

    $fixture->load($manager);
    $manager->clear();
}
```

As a result, the condition `!$uow->isInIdentityMap($reference)` in `ReferenceRepository->getReference()` will *always* evaluate to `false` after the fixture loader has finished.

## The Workaround

You can work around this by clearing out `ReferenceRepository->$identities`.  Unfortunately, you don't have direct access to this array, so you'll need to do something slightly kludgy like:

```
/* @kludge The fixture loader clears out its UnitOfWork object after
 *  loading each fixture, so we also need to clear the
 *  ReferenceRepository's identity map.
 */
$repository = $this->fixtureLoader->getReferenceRepository();
$identities = array_keys($repository->getIdentities());

foreach($identities as $key)
{
    $repository->setReferenceIdentity($key, null);
}
```

However, if you do that, you may run into some nasty `ORMInvalidArgumentException`s if you set related objects in your test fixtures:

> Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException: A new entity was found through the relationship '...' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: url. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).

## The Solution

Ultimately, if you want this to work properly, you'll need to change the behavior of the fixture executor that you use in your test cases so that it does not clear the manager after loading fixtures:

```
/** Executes data fixtures for unit tests.
 */
class TestExecutor extends ORMExecutor
{
    /** Load a fixture with the given persistence manager.
     *
     * @param ObjectManager|EntityManager $manager
     * @param FixtureInterface $fixture
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager, FixtureInterface $fixture)
    {
        /** @kludge Unfortunately, we have to copy-paste a bit of code.
         *
         * The only difference between this method and AbstractExecutor->load()
         *  is that we don't call $manager->clear() when we're done loading.
         */

        if($this->logger)
        {
            $prefix = '';
            if($fixture instanceof OrderedFixtureInterface)
            {
                $prefix = sprintf('[%d] ', $fixture->getOrder());
            }
            $this->log('loading ' . $prefix . get_class($fixture));
        }

        // additionally pass the instance of reference repository to shared fixtures
        if($fixture instanceof SharedFixtureInterface)
        {
            $fixture->setReferenceRepository($this->referenceRepository);
        }

        $fixture->load($manager);

        /* Do NOT clear the unit of work; we will keep managed entities so that
         *  they are available to tests.
         */
    }
}
```